# Automatically produce an Excel File with selected data from a custom list

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I have a Custom List containing detailed information about small business tasks that have to be carried out: the person who is assigned to the task, the current status of the task (in progress, closed, etc.), etc.

I received a requirement to produce an email (weekly) containing an Excel file with open tasks (in progress) and send it to a particular department

Normally i would run "Export to Excel" in a particular view and send the email by hand.
But the issue is this has to be an automatic process and, as far as i know, i can´t use "Export to Excel" in a Workflow.
Is there any way i can create this file using a workflow? or do you have a different approach?

Thanks!
NUNOBARBOSA

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that the exported data in excel from the SharePoint list is actually a table with a query to that view? Saving the excel file down will enable you or your users to simply refresh the data as long as the view and list exist. Check the Data tab in excel and look at the Connections section for more.

More info: https://sharepointmaven.com/export-sharepoint-excel/

Comment: Thanks Chris for your reply, very helpful. However the requirement i have if for a fully automated process : weekly build an Excel File and send it by email to department heads. Is there a way we can automate the refresh procedure and anex the file in an email? thanks Nuno